# How do I check if my laptop fan is working properly?

Tags: 12.04, fan

I have an old Dell studio 1558 laptop (2 years) with Ubuntu 12.04. Its always make some noise, some time the fan make a terrible noise - and I must quickly shutdown it by press the power button 5 seconds. When the terrible noise the laptop take really long to shutdown with the normal way (or event terminal with shutdown -h now).

I just install new Windows 8 for testing, with Windows 8 there is no noise with the fan. But I can make sure because I just use Windows for a few minute.

So is there any way (some command or program) that I can check if my fan is working properly? Does the fan need driver or something?
Thanks for all of you!

Comment: You could try to ask the same question in the dedicated [Dell support forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=342) on ubuntuforums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to the latest BIOS, if it is a software problem it will fix, because BIOS of a laptop is the driver along with all power supply for fan, But

as it seems to me that it is making some noise after some time of starting the pc, the problem may be with the hardware you must get it fixed with Dell service center, i.e.

there might be any part which get loose as it get heated, and Ubuntu is known for its heating If you run ubuntu it will consume more power than other OSes and produce more heat and less battery efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 has different power management settings, so you would need to run it for more than a few minutes to determine if the same thing happens there.

Terrible fan noises are pretty much guaranteed to be a hardware issue.  You can try cleaning your laptop fan and heatsink, either with compressed air (safer but less effective) or by taking apart the laptop and cleaning the fan & heatsink directly (riskier). My Dell laptop was making terrible noises, and the process of cleaning the fan fixed it - either from being clean or from things getting re-aligned.

Of course, disassembling the hardware will void any warranty and might cause more problems than it fixes, or you may not be comfortable doing that.